# Bounty reputation documentation

Tags: support, bounty, help-center

The [help centre](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) says "Slice off anywhere from +50 to +500 of your own hard-earned reputation, and attach it to any question as a bounty."  But when I was looking at starting a bounty for [my own question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/760867/89878), I could only choose between 100, 150 and 200.  I cannot award more because I only have 211 reputation, but why can I not award +50?

Comment: This is because you posted an answer to it. See the [MSE bounty faq](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/214632), where it states that the minimum bounty you can offer on a question you have answered is 100 rep points, instead of 50.

Comment: Aha, I suspected this might be the case.  Thanks for pointing me to the right documentation.

Comment: Actually, the Help Center gives the same info: To avoid overly promotional bounties, if you are offering a bounty on a question that you have already posted an answer to, your minimum spend is 100 reputation (not 50).  (This is the fifth bullet point in that list.)

Comment: Thanks, I must be going blind.  What's the best thing to do with my meta question?  Flag it to be closed or leave it as is?